# grails how to search in domain classes

Tags: apache, search, grails, lucene, hadoop

I have User domain class and few domain classes associated with it.
I want to be able to search in my domain classes,
and as result get all users associated with keyword.

(for example if I type "eng", it have to search in user, languages, hobbies ... 
domain classes fields values,
and get all users objects associated with those classes).

Who know any good way for this?

I have tried to search with searchable plugin,
but it does not work for hbase.

I use grails-1.3.2 and hbase-0.2.4

Answer (score 0):

You will probably have to create your own [Compass](http://www.compass-project.org/) integration since the [hbase plugin](http://www.grails.org/plugin/gorm-hbase) replaces the standard [Hibernate plugin](http://www.grails.org/plugin/hibernate).  You should start with the [Searchable plugin source code](https://github.com/gpc/grails-searchable) to get a head start.